# Autofill htaccess htpasssword in url

Tags: php, .htaccess, google-chrome, .htpasswd

I'm working on this chrome version: `Version 79.0.3945.130 (Official Build) (64 bits)`

I'm protecting assets in a specific folder: `/assets/private/`

My htaccess file work as intended.

When a user is logged, I don't like that he needs to enter the htpasswd password, I want to use this pattern to autologin, but it's not working: `http://user:password@url/assets/private/`

The prompt is shown instead of autologin, btw, Chrome is ignoring the AuthName line: `Protected data`, it shows the url instead of my rule.

Comment: Can you share more data? If htaccess works as intended, what exactly is not working? If you opened that URL containing access data on your own in another browser tab, does it work? And why is this tagged with PHP?

Comment: Chrome 19+ stopped supporting HTTP authentication credentials in the URL. See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=123150

Comment: @MrWhite , thanks, that's it, any other way to auto fill this way ? Or maybe another way to protect assets ? I'm using PHP and apache

Comment: There are endless ways of protection, we cannot recommend a specific authorization strategy you might decide to use. Placing authentication credentials in URLs is _highly_ insecure which is why it is not supported any longer.

Comment: @arkascha can you tell me example of strategy ?

Comment: That depends on what you are looking for. You have a working strategy: password based authorization, which requires the user to enter hin/her credentials prior to being able to use a resource ("login with password"). What is your issue with that? You explain in your question what does not work any more compared to the past, but you did not explain why you what that or some similar solution. There is a reason why that notation with passwords in the URL does not work any longer. That reason is valid. So what is your actual issue with that?

Comment: Users had to log in to access their private space, but I'm using images, videos for their private space, and I want to protect them from non auth user